# Extract data using HTMLParser

Tags: python, html, html-parsing, html-parser

```
<tr>
  <td style="color: #0000FF;text-align: center"><p>Sam<br/>John<br/></p></td>
</tr>
```

I am using the python [HTMLParser module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html) to extract the values Sam and John from the below html snippet, but the **handle_data** function is capturing only Sam and not John.

How I can get both Sam and John?

Comment: Is using `HTMLParser` module a requirement?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Preferably, because I have completed parsing most of the html document and only this part is remaining.

Comment: Could you provide a [**very minimal** example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) depicting your issue ? This would help to fix what might be wrong in your code.

Comment: Sorry I might have gone wrong somewhere, it is working. Will get back on this. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have an instance-level variable that would have `True`/`False` values. Set it to `True` if `p` tag started, `False` if `p` tag ended. When the value is `True`, get the data in the `handle_data()` method:

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

data = """
<tr>
  <td style="color: #0000FF;text-align: center"><p>Sam<br/>John<br/></p></td>
</tr>
"""

class Parser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.recording = False

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'p':
            self.recording = True

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        if tag == 'p':
            self.recording = False

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self.recording:
            print data

parser = Parser()
parser.feed(data)
```

Prints:

```
Sam
John
```